# Custom JSP tag file <%@ variable ..> doesn't work?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I want to define a custom JSP tag, which produces a HTML table with alternating row background colors. Therefore the CSS classes "odd" and "even" are set depending on the row index of the table.

The example without the JSP tag works fine and the question is: What's going wrong in the custom tag example below? How can I  pass the variable "rowIndex" through both custom tags?

The reference http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html doesn't help.

Thanks

**Example JSP page that works:**

```
<c:set var="rowIndex" value="1"/>
<table class="datatable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="${(rowIndex %2 == 0) ? 'odd' : 'even'}"><c:set var="rowIndex" value="${rowIndex+1}"/>
            <td width="200px"><bean:message key='myKey' /></td>
            <td>todoValue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class=${(rowIndex %2 == 0) ? 'odd' : 'even'}><c:set var="rowIndex" value="${rowIndex+1}"/>
            <td><bean:message key='myKey' /></td>
            <td>todoValue</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Example JSP page with custom tag that doesn't work:**

JSP page

```
<%@taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="myApp"%>

....

<myApp:keyValueDataTable>
    <myApp:keyValueDataTableRow />
    <myApp:keyValueDataTableRow />
    <myApp:keyValueDataTableRow />
</myApp:keyValueDataTable>
```

dataTable.tag

```
<%@ include file='/tiles/taglibs.inc'%>
<%@tag description="Description" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ variable name-given="rowIndex" %> 
<c:set var="rowIndex" value="1" />

<table class="datatable">
    <tbody>
        <jsp:doBody/>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

tableRow.tag

```
<%@ include file='/tiles/taglibs.inc'%>
<%@tag description="Description" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ variable name-given="rowIndex" %> 

        <tr class="${(rowIndex %2 == 0) ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
            <c:set var="rowIndex" value="${rowIndex+1}" />
            <td width="200px"><c:out value="Index=${rowIndex}"></c:out> <bean:message key='myKey' /></td>
            <td>todoValue</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the URI syntax?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="utils" uri="http://www.example.com/tld/utils"%>
```

Comment: Do you mean replace "<%@taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="myApp"%>
" with "<%@ taglib prefix="utils" uri="http://www.example.com/tld/utils"%>"? That's not working, because the is defined in the file in /WEB-INF/tags.

Answer (score 0):

To pass variable from your page into tag use attribute directive. Add this in your tag file:

```
<%@ attribute name="rowIndex" required="true" type="java.lang.Integer" %>
```

And in jsp that use this tag just add rowIndex as tag attribute.

Comment: I tried this and the result is that the attribute is passed as value and not as reference in the tag. So the change (rowIndex+1) is only in tableRow.tag available and not passed to the next "<myApp:keyValueDataTableRow />"

Comment: just create one more parameter in next tag and pass there new value.